# Getting error "Maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, runtime-error

So I just received an error that I kinda don't understand what is the reason of.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\utils.py", line 657, in script
    logger.warn('Wopsiy! No word found!')
  File "C:\Users\utils.py", line 30, in warn
    sys.stdout.write("{}{} {}".format(self.__timestamp(), '[' + self.name + '] -', colored(text, "yellow")))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 166, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, start)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 40, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 141, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 169, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 174, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
```

As I can see it has something with the logger that I have created myself that looks like:

### Utils class

```
from datetime import datetime
from termcolor import cprint, colored
import sys

import colorama

class Logger:

    def __init__(self,name):
        colorama.init()
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def __timestamp():
        timestamp = str(datetime.now().strftime("[%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+"]")
        return timestamp

    def warn(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write("{}{} {}".format(self.__timestamp(), '[' + self.name + '] -', colored(text, "yellow")))
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

And basically I made also a simple code of how my code looks like as well:

```
from utils import Logger
logger = Logger('Script')

def main():
    logger = Logger("product_info")
    word = ['Nope', 'There', 'Is', 'No', 'Word']
    while True:

        try:

            for _ in infinity():
                 if 'Hello' in word:
                     print('WORKS!!')

            else:
                logger.warn('Wopsiy! No word found!')
                time.sleep(1)

         except Exception as err:
              print(err)
              time.sleep(1)
              continue
```

So the problem is that after a while it gives me an error of `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` but I only get it whenever I print out `except Exception as err:` but when I see through a console it gives me the output that is given at the top.

The question is now that I have actually no idea what the cause of it is.

### Edit

```
from datetime import datetime
from termcolor import cprint, colored
import sys

import colorama
colorama.init()
class Logger:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def __timestamp():
        timestamp = str(datetime.now().strftime("[%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]+"]")
        return timestamp

    def warn(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write("{}{} {}".format(self.__timestamp(), '[' + self.name + '] -', colored(text, "yellow")))
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Looks like an instance of this issue: https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/140

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the issue may happen when you call colorama.init() several times. Try moving this invocation out of the Logger constructor into the global scope.

Comment: @KT.You might be very right, Do you have any example how moving out form Logger into a global would help?

Comment: Just put colorama.init right after import colorama. As far as I understand this init call wraps global streams with colorama filters, and when you re-wrap them again (by calling colorama.init multiple times) things just get worse.

Comment: For example, the line "for i in range(1000): colorama.init()" manages to crash the interpreter for me.

Comment: Would that be the same error as I ahve given ? @KT.

Comment: @KT. - I have added an Edit. Did you mean like that?

Comment: No, I don't even get a clean exception - the interpreter simply crashes with "Error in sys.excepthook, Original exception was: " and nothing else. Anyway, the point is that you don't want to call "init" multiple times.

Re: Edit. Yes, that's what I meant. See if you still get your exception now.

Comment: So If I have it outside the *class* like right below `import colorama` would that count as it doesn't call it multiple times? - Edit: Oh okey! I will try and give it a go and see. I will still continue to have this thread open :)

Comment: When you call colorama.init inside the constructor of your Logger, you call it every time you construct a Logger. Otherwise the init executes only when the module is first imported.

Comment: @KT. Also calling logger = Logger('Hello') is not an issue unless that causing `maximum recursion depth exceeded` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184183/discussion-between-kt-and-hellosiroverthere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood from the discussion in the comments to the question, you may create multiple instances of the `Logger` class during the execution of your script. Each creation of a `Logger` invokes `colorama.init()`. Each call to `colorama.init()` forces Colorama to replace `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` streams with colorama-wrapped versions of them.

After more and more calls to `colorama.init` your streams turn into fat onions of lots of (uselessly repeated) colorama wrapper layers, and a single call to `print` has to get passed recursively from layer to layer until it reaches the actual `sys.stdout`.

When the number of layers exceeds the maximum allowed stack depth, you get your exception. This situation is also referenced in [this open colorama issue](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/140).

The easiest way to fix the problem would be to move `colorama.init()` out of the `Logger` constructor, and have something like that globally instead:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

Comment: This seem to be the actually issue and I will try give it a go and give it few hours! I will come back if no issues comes up!

Comment: Seems to work! Tried it for 2 days and not a single error!